# WCF rest service http to https error 404

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, ssl, https

I'm working with visual Studio 2015. I have a Xamarin Cross-Platfom's project.
My WCF Rest Service works fine with http.  I tried to use HTTPS but I receive a "404 error not found" when I try to access my resource.
You will find below the configs files:

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>

 <appSettings>
   <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="PrototypeBHost.PrototypeB"   behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity"
    behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
    contract="PrototypeBHost.IprototypeB" />

<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex" />     
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
   <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

applicationhost.config

```
<site name="PrototypeBHost" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\Users\Ludovic\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PrototypeB\PrototypeBHost" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
            <!--    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9612:192.168.1.106" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8023:localhost" />-->
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:9612:192.168.1.106" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:8023:localhost" />  
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

I followed some tutorials about WCF Rest but I'm a little bit confused with the SSL certificat. Do I need it? How can I attach the ssl certificat to the WCF Rest Service? Did I miss something?

[My_WCF_proprieties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IFu9.png)

Comment: Did you configure IIS to work with SSL?

Comment: No, I linked a picture in the end of my post with my wcf proprieties.  I will check this.

Comment: Can you create a github repo with a simplified version of your service?

Comment: Yes for development you need a self signed certificate to test. You can get more info from [social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32524.a-complete-guide-to-create-secure-wcf-rest-api-with-ssl-and-basic-authentication.aspx)

Comment: My project on github https://github.com/ludovicLegl/ServiceWCFPrototype/tree/master/PrototypeBHost

Comment: IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: IIS Express 10.0

Comment: I try to configure SSL on IIS with self signed certificat. Now if I start the Rest Service on IIS. I have this error
SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG. I'm checking how ot solve it.

Comment: Siva Gopal I don't figure out how to link my service with the IIS Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found where was the problem, the default certificate with IIS Express doesn't work and cause some trouble. 
First, I delete one of the certificate, I use command prompt for VS2015

```
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300
```

after that 
I add  a self-signed certificate

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300 certhash=fb02ea72ab7443604aa8frib298e43l751ce3606 appid={214124cd-d05b-4309-8p76-9caa44b2b74a}
```

the command to show all certificates

```
netsh http show sslcert > output.txt
```

and it works :)